# Do I need to worry about the number of tasks I create?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I tried to find something online with regards to this but there doesn't seem to be a definite answer. I just have my own reasoning and would like to know what is the best way.

My application runs through a long list of files(about 100-200) and does some calculations on the data inside of them. Each file takes a few minutes to process.

I originally planned on creating Tasks based on the number of cores in the processor.

So if there are 4 cores, then I would create 3 tasks and have each task process 1/3 of the files.

My reading has told me that the thread pool manages all task and according creates threads for it based on a variety of factors.(in simple terms?)

Would it then be better for me to simply create a task for each file and allow the thread pool to decide what is best?

Any info, suggestion would be very welcome! Thanks

EDIT: All the files are about 5MB, and the calculations/analysis of the data in the files is very processor heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

200 files isn't such a long list, but I would still recommend against flooding the ThreadPool with pending tasks.

You can use TPL Dataflow's ActionBlock for this. You create the block, give it an action to perform on each item and limit the parallelism to whatever you want.

Example in C#:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<string>(async fileName =>
{
    var data = await ReadFileAsync(fileName);
    ProcessData(data);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 });

foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
{
    block.Post(fileName);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

Since it's not just a CPU bound operation you should use a higher number than the available CPUs. Consider using a config file so you can change it according to actual performance.

Comment: Thanks will look more into this. This actually is a CPU bound operation, all the analysis it does with the data in the file is very heavy on the CPU that is why I am trying to see what works best.

Comment: @Rio but reading the files is I/O. If it's negligible then you can stick with a lower limit though.

Comment: Thanks! I will be giving this a try as it seems the best way of doing it. Is there a reason I should go lower if it is CPU bound?

Comment: @Rio Only if you have other operations that are heavy on CPU usage. But even then the ThreadPool can probably handle that anyway...

Answer (score 2):

> based on a variety of factors

That is a key point. It is unpredictable (to me) how many threads will actually be running for non-CPU bound work under full load. The .NET thread pool heuristics are very volatile (subjectively: insane) and should not be relied upon.

> allow the thread pool to decide what is best

It can't know. It is (mostly) good at scheduling CPU-bound work but it can't find the optimal degree of parallelism for IO bound work.

Use PLINQ:

```
myFiles
.AsParallel().WithDOP(optimalDopHere)
.ForAll(x => Process(x));
```

Determine the optimal degree of parallelism empirically.

If this is purely CPU-bound work you can get away with pretty much any parallel construct, probably `Parallel` or still PLINQ.

Comment: It is actually more CPU-bound. Once each file's data is loaded, the analysis on the file is all CPU bound and very heavy on processing. We are using SSD's so the loading of the file is very quick. But I still see your point where, it is probably better for me to handle the tasks than to leave it upto the thread pool